# Firefox doesn't like inline CSS in an XSL file for a Sharepoint list?

Tags: css, xslt

Works fine in FF/IE if I include a link to a stylesheet, but I'd rather include the CSS inline so everything is in the one XSL file so it's easier to distibuute. When I do, IE works but FF drops a style for one element; that style is in a separate stylesheet, not the inline styling.

Specifically:

HTML:

`<ul id =navbar class=**PrimaryNavFrame**><li><a href="http://mysite.com/contactus.aspx">Contact</a><ul><li><a href="h.......`

The styling for the PrimaryNavFrame class gets dropped *only* in FF. It appears in the source, etc. The inline styling itself works.

I'm not used to Firefox having a problem with what seems pretty straightforward so was wondering if anyone has any ideas?

Update:
If I remove float, it works, but I need the float (it's a horizontal menu):

```
#navbar li {display:inline;   list-style: none;   float: left ;height:25px; }
```

Is there a way to get the float without disrupting the external CSS?

Another update:

It seems all I had to do was add the float to the class that was getting dropped and it works!

```
.PrimaryNavFrame{float:left;}
```

Thanks for the responses!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038101/how-to-inline-css-and-javascript-through-xsl

Comment: @jmort253: I don't think so. That one is about including an unparsed entity.

Comment: Do note that inline style (`style` element) has more precedence in the "cascade" than external stylesheets.

Comment: There's only one declaration for this class (in an external sheet) and nothing in the inline styling to override it. The problem seems to be the float in the inline styling. If I remove it, it works as it should but od course I need the float because this is for a horizontal menu. I added more specific info to the question.

Comment: You should add your answer as an actual answer in the answers section, and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another update:

It seems all I had to do was add the float to the class that was getting dropped and it works!

.PrimaryNavFrame{float:left;}

Thanks for the responses!